How can I create, update separate changelog.md for multiple .csproj projects in a single repository?
There is 1 shared repository (contains .git), pp_shared_lib, which has several projects added to it. It is not possible to separate projects into repositories separate from pp_shared_lib. What are the ways to maintain your own changelog (not just 1 common one) for each project in the repository? The option with submodule, as I understand it, is not suitable, since for this each project must have its own repository. Now, for the task of auto incrementing the version and maintaining the changelog locally (in the current branch), I use the Versionize library in .net core projects, which, when adding > 1 project, throws an exception about “not unambiguously selecting a project for versioning.” What are the possible solutions?
P.S. Used by git.
Architecture:
3 projects .csproj in repository pp_shared_lib
Library:
https://github.com/versionize/versionize
I read about submodules, but for them you need to create a separate repository for each library. I don't have permission for this. Link reviewed: GIT Version Control setup for multiple projects with shared code

Do you update the changelogs manually? Then use different file names or put them into separate folders. Does it generated automatically with your tool? Read the manual.
